# What's the proper way of configuring a SoapActionSmartEndpointInterceptor along with AnnotationActionEndpointMapping

Tags: java, spring-ws

AbstractAddressingEndpointMapping (an ancestor of AnnotationActionEndpointMapping) retrieves all SmartInterceptors from the BeanFactory and assigns them to an instance variable.  Later the MessageDispatcher (SoapMessageDispatcher) calls getEndpoint() on the mapping (from within its own getEndpoint() method).  AbstractAddressingEndpointMapping.getEndpoint() calls its own private getEndpointInvocationChain() method that creates a new instance of SoapEndpointInvocationChain with all the interceptors.  It never calls shouldIntercept() on the interceptor to determine whether it should be added to the chain.

Contract this to SoapActionAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping, which inherits from AbstractEndpointMapping which does the same thing in regards to retrieving the SmartInterceptors.  However, it's getEndpoint() method actually calls shouldIntercept() on each interceptor and only adds ones that return true to its chain.  AnnotationActionEndpointMapping and SoapActionAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping have different ancestors so their handling is obviously different.

So the question is -- is there a proper way to configure SmartInterceptors for an AnnotationActionEndpointMapping?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Sorry @philtune, I thought that would be evident since the post was tagged with spring-ws.  The answer is Java.

Comment: Cool, I'm Java-illiterate... just wanted to add the `java` tag to attract more answerers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a bug: the `AnnotationActionEndpointMapping` should also call `shouldIntercept` on its smart interceptor chain. Could you please create a JIRA for this [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWS), possibly linking to this SO question? Or better yet, provide a [pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws/)?

Comment: Thanks @Arjen -- I've opened https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWS-883 with a pull request.

Comment: SWS-883 has been resolved via https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws/pull/27. Thanks!